# adding captions outside of a figure or table?

Tags: fonts, captions, line-numbering

For my thesis, I have written a computer program that reads in a parameter file. I want to show the parameter file in my thesis but am not sure what the best way to go about this is.

Ultimately, I want to show the parameter file in some sort of typewriter-like font (say Courier) with a caption. I would also like to show the line numbers for the parameter file. What's the best way to do this?

I know how to do line numbers and change the font, but I don't know how to give a caption to some random text that is not really a figure.

Aside: should the parameter file be shown as a "figure" or a "table"?

Answer (score 14):

You can easily treat your parameter file as a standard `figure` or a `table`; in the third example code below I used this approach.

To add captions outside floating environments, you could use the `\captionof` command from the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) (or [capt-of](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) package; in the last example code below I used this approach.

To have automatic number line, monospaced font and listing-like feeling, one option would be to use the highly customizable [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{% general command to set parameter(s)
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% print whole listing small and with monospaced font
numbers=left% number lines to the left
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Parameter file used elsewhere}]
column1a column2a column3a
column1b column2b column3b
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option could be the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=lines,label={A parameter file used elsewhere},numbers=left,numbersep=10pt]
column1a column2a column3a
column1b column2b column3b
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to treat your parameter file as a table (or a figure), you can wrap the `Verbatim` environment inside a `table` (or a `figure`) environment; notice that this implies that now you are dealing with a floating object:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A parameter file used elsewhere}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,numbersep=10pt]
column1a column2a column3a
column1b column2b column3b
\end{Verbatim}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\captionof` you can give your parameter list a caption such as those used for the `figure` or the `table` environment, but without using a floating environment. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{A parameter file used elsewhere}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,numbersep=10pt]
column1a column2a column3a
column1b column2b column3b
\end{Verbatim}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{A parameter file used elsewhere}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,numbersep=10pt]
column1a column2a column3a
column1b column2b column3b
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

to prevent page breaks inside the environment.

Comment: Thanks for that great response. I like the last example... However, I'm seeing my text get split across different pages. Is it possible to keep the text together without splitting across pages? Thanks.

Comment: @FluxCapacitor: sure. See my updated answer.

Comment: I would prefer solution using `listings`. IMHO pieces of code/configuration files/... should be floating, and the name "Listings" seems to be the most proper one. Besides the `listings` package, one can creat new type of float using the [`float` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show your parameter file is just to place everything in a verbatim environment.  You get a fixed width font automatically.

```
\begin{verbatim}
numbers and text
\end{verbatim}
```

Figure and table environments are generic and really only differ in how the captions are titled, e.g., Figure 3.1 or Table 3.1 and what shows up in the `listoffigures` or `listoftables`  So the choice of where to put your code fragments should be based on that.

There are other packages (like fancyvrb) that might be better suited to your particular problem if you want auto-numbering of lines or other features.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to automate the creation of certain `table` and `figure` floats that (i) should have their contents set in a typewriter (aka "monospaced") font automatically and (ii) otherwise share all features of the "regular" table/figure environments.

One way to achieve this is to define two new environments called, say, `twtable` and `twfigure` (short for typewriter-table and typewriter-figure), as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{twtable}%
    {\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault \selectfont%
     \@float{table}}
    {\end@float}
\newenvironment{twfigure}%
    {\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault \selectfont%
     \@float{figure}}
    {\end@float}
\makeatother
```

If you insert this code snippet into your document's preamble, all `twtable` and `twfigure` floats will be typeset in typewriter font but otherwise be indistinguishable from `table` and `figure` floats.